# modify scala map values

Tags: scala, dictionary

I has learn scala recently,but I found a question when modify map values.

```
    def exercise1():Map[String, Int]={
      val map = createMap()
      var newMap = map
     for((k,v) <-  map){
       newMap(k) = 2 * v;
     }
      newMap
    }
```

the function exercise1 can running. But when I change a line like next

```
newMap(k) = v * 2;
```

I found it failed, why?

Comment: can you share what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: You say changing `2 * v` to `v * 2` makes if fail? Fail how? It no longer compiles? Does it run with different results? Please clarify.

Comment: "it failed" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* failed? *How* did it fail? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, and edge cases?

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure what `createMap()` function returns, but my guess is that it returns a `Map[String, Int]`.

If this is true, then your code fails because `Map[String, Int]` is immutable, and you can't reassign value to immutable map with this code `newMap(k) = 2 * v`. You must use `mutable.Map[String, Int]` here.

Example code (in scala REPL):

```
scala> val x = Map("foo" -> 1, "bar" -> 2)
x: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(foo -> 1, bar -> 2)

scala> var y: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Int] = scala.collection.mutable.Map(x.toSeq: _*)
y: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(foo -> 1, bar -> 2)

scala> y("foo") = 3

scala> y
res2: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(foo -> 3, bar -> 2)
```

However, what you need here is just a new map with all the values being doubled, you can simply do:

```
x.map { case (k, v) => k -> 2 * v }
```